# Assistance with writing a loop to return data

Tags: c#, .net, foreach, sqldatasource

I have one table where they have multiple employees assigned to multiple managers. The data gets imported from an excel file from HR. I need to cycle through the table and find the number of employees assigned to each manager, group them together, and send that manager one email instead of multiple separate ones. I am having trouble on how to write a loop to do this. I am new to coding. Thank you.

```
All of the fields:
 [ Reports To Name]
      ,[ Last Name]
      ,[ Middle Initial]
      ,[ First Name]
      ,[ Department #]
      ,[ Department]
      ,[ Job Code-Title]
      ,[Form Due Date]
      ,[Current Route Step Name]
      ,[ Status]
      ,[ Company]
      ,[Manager Email]
```

---

```
//Get all of the records
  public DataTable OCCheckList()
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM dbo.OrientationChecklistTest", _connectionString);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }

//Count the number of times the manager shows up in the table
    public DataTable OCCount(string ManagerEmail)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT COUNT([Manager Email]) AS EmployeeCount FROM [dbo].[OrientationChecklistTest] WHERE [Manager Email]='@ManagerEmail' GROUP BY [Manager Email]", _connectionString);
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ManagerEmail", ManagerEmail);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }

//Find the names and additional information about the employees for each manager
    public DataTable OCManager(string ManagerEmail)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [Manager Email], [ First Name], [ Last Name], [Current Route Step Name], [Form Due Date] From dbo.OrientationChecklistTest WHERE [Manager Email]='@ManagerEmail' ORDER BY [Manager Email]", _connectionString);
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ManagerEmail", ManagerEmail);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }





 protected void btnEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DataTable dtCheck = OCCheckList();
    string managerEmail = "";
    string currManager = "";
    string firstName = "";
    string lastName = "";
    string reportsTo = "";
    string currReportsTo = "";
    string dueDate = "";
    string stepName = "";
    int count = 0;
    MailMessage myMessage = new MailMessage();
    myMessage.Body = "Please be advised that tasks for the following employees has been assigned to you and is available in your To Do Tile. <br /><br />If you have any questions, do not reply to this e-mail, please contact: Help at <a href=\"mailto:Help@company.org\">Help@company.org</a>. <br /> <br /> Thank you. <br /> <br /> Please click the link to log in to SuccessFactors: <a href=\"http://url.org\">Click Here</a><br /> <br />----------------<br /> <br />";

    /*  foreach (DataRow row in dtCheck.Rows)
      {
          managerEmail = Convert.ToString(row["Manager Email"]);
          reportsTo = Convert.ToString(row[" Reports To Name"]);

          DataTable dtCount = OCCount(managerEmail);
          int numberOfRecords = 0;
              foreach (DataRow row3 in dtCount.Rows)
              {
                      if (row3["Manager Email"].ToString() == managerEmail)
                      {
                          numberOfRecords++;
                      }
                  Console.WriteLine("Count: " + numberOfRecords.ToString());

                  DataTable dtManager = OCManager(managerEmail);

                  foreach (DataRow row2 in dtManager.Rows)
                  { 
                      firstName = Convert.ToString(row[" First Name"]);
                      lastName = Convert.ToString(row[" Last Name"]);
                      dueDate = Convert.ToString(row["Form Due Date"]);
                      stepName = Convert.ToString(row["Current Route Step Name"]);
                      myMessage.Body += "<strong>Employee Name:</strong> " + firstName + " " + lastName + "<br /><strong>Task Due:</strong> " + stepName + "<br /><strong>Due Date:</strong> " + dueDate + "<br />-----<br />";
                      count++;

                          if (count == numberOfRecords)
                          {
                              break;
                          }
                  }
                      myMessage.Subject = "SuccessFactors Message for " + reportsTo;
                      myMessage.From = new MailAddress("SuccessFactorsHelp@atlanticare.org", "AtlantiCare Human Resources");
                      myMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(managerEmail, reportsTo));
                      myMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
                      string sSmtpServer = "smtp.atlanticare.org";

                      SmtpClient mySmtpClient = new SmtpClient();
                      mySmtpClient.Host = sSmtpServer;
                      try
                      {
                          Thread t1 = new Thread(delegate ()
                          {
                              mySmtpClient.Send(myMessage);
                              myMessage.Body = "";
                          });
                          t1.Start();
                          lblMessage.Text += "<center>Email sent to: " + managerEmail + "<br /></center>";
                      }
                      catch
                      {
                          lblError.Text += "<center>Email <font color=\"red\">FAILURE</font> to: " + managerEmail + "<br /></center>";
                      }
              break;
              }
      }
      */
    DataTable dtCount = OCCount(managerEmail);
    int numberOfRecords = 0;
    foreach (DataRow row3 in dtCount.Rows)
    {
        if (row3["Manager Email"].ToString() == managerEmail)
        {
            numberOfRecords++;
        }
    }

    foreach (DataRow row in dtCheck.Rows)
    {
        if (managerEmail == "")
        {
            managerEmail = Convert.ToString(row["Manager Email"]);
            reportsTo = Convert.ToString(row[" Reports To Name"]);
            currManager = Convert.ToString(row["Manager Email"]);
            currReportsTo = Convert.ToString(row[" Reports To Name"]);
        }
        else
        {
            managerEmail = Convert.ToString(row["Manager Email"]);
            reportsTo = Convert.ToString(row[" Reports To Name"]);
        }

        if (currManager == managerEmail)
        {
            Response.Write("First IF<br />");
            firstName = Convert.ToString(row[" First Name"]);
            lastName = Convert.ToString(row[" Last Name"]);
            dueDate = Convert.ToString(row["Form Due Date"]);
            stepName = Convert.ToString(row["Current Route Step Name"]);
            myMessage.Body += "<strong>Employee Name:</strong> " + firstName + " " + lastName + "<br /><strong>Task Due:</strong> " + stepName + "<br /><strong>Due Date:</strong> " + dueDate + "<br />-----<br />";
        }

        if (currManager != managerEmail)
        {
            Response.Write("Second IF<br />");
            myMessage.Subject = "SuccessFactors Message for " + reportsTo;
            myMessage.From = new MailAddress("Help@company.org", "Human Resources");
            myMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(managerEmail, reportsTo));
            myMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
            string sSmtpServer = "smtp.company.org";

            SmtpClient mySmtpClient = new SmtpClient();
            mySmtpClient.Host = sSmtpServer;
                try
                {
                    Thread t1 = new Thread(delegate ()
                    {
                        mySmtpClient.Send(myMessage);
                    });
                    t1.Start();
                    lblMessage.Text += "<center>Email sent to: " + managerEmail + "<br /></center>";  
                }
                catch
                {
                    lblError.Text += "<center>Email <font color=\"red\">FAILURE</font> to: " + managerEmail + "<br /></center>";
                }

            currManager = managerEmail;
            myMessage.Body = "Please be advised that tasks for the following employees has been assigned to you and is available in your To Do Tile. <br /><br />If you have any questions, do not reply to this e-mail, please contact: Help at <a href=\"mailto:Help@company.org\">Help@company.org</a>. <br /> <br /> Thank you. <br /> <br /> Please click the link to log in to SuccessFactors: <a href=\"http://url.org\">Click Here</a><br /> <br />----------------<br /> <br />";
            firstName = Convert.ToString(row[" First Name"]);
            lastName = Convert.ToString(row[" Last Name"]);
            reportsTo = Convert.ToString(row[" Reports To Name"]);
            dueDate = Convert.ToString(row["Form Due Date"]);
            stepName = Convert.ToString(row["Current Route Step Name"]);
            myMessage.Body += "<strong>Employee Name:</strong> " + firstName + " " + lastName + "<br /><strong>Task Due:</strong> " + stepName + "<br /><strong>Due Date:</strong> " + dueDate + "<br />-----<br />";
        }

        Response.Write("Mgr: " + managerEmail + "<br />");
        Response.Write("CurrMgr: " + currManager + "<br /><br />");

    }

    }


}
```

Sample Data:
[SampleData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNgBr.png)

Data I Want:
[DataIWant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGelG.png)

That way I can send each manager an email of the items they have due grouped together with all of the employees underneath them.

Comment: Can you show the sample data and expected the result?

Comment: Added it. Thanks

Comment: You just need the results from OCCheckList, except they should be ordered by the manager email. Loop through the rows. Set a variable to maintain who the current manager is. Each time you loop, check the manager in that row is still the same as the manager before. If so, append these details to your current email. If not, then send the email of the previous manager's details, and then start a new one. Repeat until you've used all the rows.

Comment: Thank you, this gives me a good layout on how to go about it.